# Beyond 180 degrees rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my object's rotation to go beyond 180 degrees when I add rotations to it. Currently it goes into negative after it reaches 180. How do I avoid this from happening?

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)){
            this.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, this.transform.localEulerAngles.y+ 70f, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Ex. -90 degrees and 270 degrees are equivalent for almost every use case. But if you do need to, you could just convert it... any negative rotation X is equivalent to 360 - X.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Could you please post as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Rotations are always within 0-360. As mentioned by Declan, you could convert them to be legible using this formula.
Mathf.Abs(angle % 360)

Comment: in this case -90 would result in 90 and not 270